# Should I store private data in a blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I saw some linked questions about this subject that it is possible to store private data;  in a blockchain. But the question here is: should I do that? Cause the data is there forever. And encryptions we cannot hack today are possibly easy to hack in about twenty years.. So what to do with private data?

Comment: In the future decryption will be illegal or against terms of service. It is like decompiling binaries today. You could not publicly admit that you decompiled Photoshop, because Adobe would sue you for breaking license agrement. Also , in some countries giving out private data is illegal, and you could lose millions if such law is violated, so you must check with a lawer first if storing data on block chain will violate these laws, because you are not storing it in your own space, you are giving it away for everybody to store, even if it is encrypted.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. What are the requirements for privacy? Is this health data? State secrets? Coupon code for $2 off ice cream expiring next month? Your prediction for the 2018 Stanley Cup winner? And why are you thinking of storing the data in the blockchain? As an alternative to off-site back up? To share with a friend? A sealed bet? Because you want a safe place to store private data? Authenticating yourself? What form of encryption are you planning on using? OTP? Deniable encryption method? Something more conventional?

Answer (score 0):

Its up to every single individual.

1. What will one do with your private data after 20 years!? By then you yourself may not need it.
2. All they can do is read your private data and may not modify it, as they have to hack every single node in the entire chain. Imaging the size of the chain after 20 years.

So decide yourself to keep it or not. And my answer to your question is **should not** keep it.